# Importing `.graphql` files are undefined

Tags: angular, graphql, apollo-client

I'm trying to import `.grahphql` files into my angular project. I followed the following "tutorial": https://apollo-angular.com/docs/recipes/webpack

But something goes wrong, if I do:

```
import someQuery from '../../graphql/GetPrimarySystemsQuery.graphql';

export class something {

    function test() {
        console.log(someQuery )
    }
}
```

I get `undefined` in my console

but if I do the following:

```
import * as someQuery from '../../graphql/rankingSystem/queries/GetPrimarySystemsQuery.graphql';

export class something {

    function test() {
        console.log(someQuery )
    }
}
```

It works, this seems to be different from what the documentation everywhere suggests, but I have no clue on why this happens

Comment: Just confirming you had done this step: "You can load this file adding a rule in your webpack config file" -- looks like it needs a webpack config to expose/parse those files for use elsewhere in the app.

Comment: @NathanBeck Yes I have that in my webpack config file, would it be able to load the `.graphql` files without it?